# Default permission of `/var/www` folder in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions

I have just hosted my website on Amazon AWS. It is working fine, but all files are publicly accessible.

like hitting url

`mywebsite.com/uploads/` giving the list of all files.

`mywebsite.com/php_code/` is giving the list of whole php codes.

How can I prevent this?

I have read this is something related to file permissions. but I am new to Ubuntu so can't get it.

Comment: This question shall be made to ask.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

You could just stick a blank `index.html` file in each directory so that the default Apache behavior of listing files in a directory in the event of no index.html (or index.php) doesn't occur. You'll see that in CMS's like Wordpress.

You could also add `Options -Indexes` to your `.htaccess` file so that Apache won't list files in the directory.

In the end, this isn't an Ubuntu problem, it's not a file permission problem, it's not an AWS problem. It's actually an Apache problem, and it's doing what it's supposed to do.